# Lazarus - No Form Window, Dialogue Grey'd Out

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I've got a wee bit of experience with Pascal, as I've used it to create mods via TES5Edit for Skyrim, and I've hit a wee snag with modding Dark Souls, and I figured flexin' me Pascalerrific muscles would be a good exercise.

But, uh, it's all buggered right from the get go. Lazarus supposedly has this "Form Window" feature, where ya can just click one of the icons and then click on the IDE, and bam. Automated GUI creation.

I ain't got that. The window isn't up, and the option to open it is grey'd out. 'Eres an image to demonstrate:

['Ere 'tis, lads.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBvYu.png)

Bit sad that, right from the get go, I'm flummoxed. LEND ME YO' EARS, MA HOMIES! A BROTHA NEEDS AID!

*Achem* So, uh, what do I do to enable it? Google gives absolutely nothing in regards to using Lazarus in pretty much any way, so that bridge wasn't even built 'afore it was burnt.

Comment: FWIW, a wee less of your dialect(s) would make your messages easier to understand for those who can only read plain English.

Answer (score 2):

You have to click on "File -> New Form" in the menu to create a new form class.

If that menu entry is disabled as well, first create a new project and make sure to select "Project > Application"

Comment: YAARRRR! THAT BE THE FIX TO ME OL' PRO'LLEM! YARR BE HAVIN' ME THANKS YE BE!